# mysql password error and close

Tags: mysql, passwords

When I run the MYSQL 5.7 command line client, it says 'Enter password'. I entered the password correctly, but the error message appears briefly and exits quickly. So I can not see the error message in detail. How can we solve it?

Answer (score 0):

are you input this command on your terminal ?

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Comment: I input that command but the following sentence came out. 
"'mysql' is an internal or external command, an executable program, or
This is not a batch file."